# why background image not showing but if I put background color it's working?

Tags: html, css, smint

I use smint 3.0 for my webpage and I want to put some background picture but it doesn't work with pictures only with colors. I've tried with different pictures.

```
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #e5e5e5;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-image: url("pictures/background.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Seems likely that you may not be pointing to the right location for the image. Can you share your directory structure?

Comment: Maybe could the picture you're trying to use not be located? Try to use the absolute path for testing. If this works your relative path is wrong in some way.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in an example for us? I think Julian may be correct.

Comment: my pictures is in folder pictures and the name is background and it is jpg

Comment: can u post your folder structure..??

Comment: D:\Projects\Portfolio\Portfolio\Portfolio\pictures                            index.html is here: D:\Projects\Portfolio\Portfolio\Portfolio

Comment: the problem is the path, I met the same problem before. Did you try to use the absolute path? U can try  `../pictures/background.jpg` or `/pictures/background.jpg` in your browser to test. Switch to network tab to ensure the browser is getting the file

Comment: Find where is your picture relative to css file.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working, but you haven't supplied much detail of your problem.
I added your code to a fiddle and included the smint 3.0 and jquery, and a background image shows up okay.

```
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #e5e5e5;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-image: url("http://www.crystalxp.net/galerie/img/img-wallpapers-windows-vista-editions-bg-pack-vaca-13740.jpg");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/joshvito/0tk25trf/

Comment: @user3531532 check that your path to the image is correct, eg. url("pictures/background.jpg");

Comment: when the picture is from the web it works, i will change the path from the local picture to the web and it works...